# Showing an Autocorrelation Formula is True

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading a thesis and I am trying to show an autocorrelation formula is true.

We have the process:
$$
P(t) = |V|^2 + |v(t)|^2 + Vv^*(t) + V^*v(t)
$$

, where $V$ is a constant complex number and $v(t)$ is a zero-mean complex Gaussian process with autocorrelation function defined as:
$$
r(\tau) = E[v^*(t)v(t+\tau)].
$$

Also, we know that $E[|v(t)|^2] = \sigma^2$.

How do I show that the autocorrelation of $P(t)$ is:
$$
E[P(t)P(t+\tau)] = |V|^4 + 2|V|^2\sigma^2 + E[|v(t)|^2|v(t+\tau)|^2] + |V|^2 r(\tau) + |V|^2 r^*(\tau)
$$

I have reached an expression which is close to the given expression, and I am trying to see how to progress. My work:

The expectation is a product of two 4-terms, therefore after expansion, there must be 16 terms, and some of those terms could be zero.
$$
\begin{align*}
E[P(t)P(t+\tau)] & = E[[|V|^2 + |v(t)|^2 + Vv^*(t) + V^*v(t)][|V|^2 + |v(t+\tau)|^2 + Vv^*(t+\tau) + V^*v(t+\tau)]] \\
& = E[|V|^2|V|^2 + |V|^2|v(t+\tau)|^2 + |V|^2Vv^*(t+\tau)+|V|^2V^*v(t+\tau) \\
& +\ |v(t)|^2|V|^2 + |v(t)|^2|v(t+\tau)|^2 + |v(t)|^2Vv^*(t+\tau)+|v(t)|^2V^*v(t+\tau) \\
& +\ Vv^*(t)[|V|^2 + |v(t+\tau)|^2 + Vv^*(t+\tau) + V^*v(t+\tau)] \\
& +\ V^*v(t)[|V|^2 + |v(t+\tau)|^2 + Vv^*(t+\tau) + V^*v(t+\tau)]]. \\
& = |V|^4 + |V|^2\sigma^2 + 0 + 0 \\
& +\ \sigma^2|V|^2 + E[|v(t)|^2|v(t+\tau)|^2] + E[|v(t)|^2Vv^*(t+\tau)]+E[|v(t)|^2V^*v(t+\tau)] \\
& +\ 0 + E[Vv^*(t)|v(t+\tau)|^2] + V^2E[v^*(t)v^*(t+\tau)] + |V|^2r(\tau) \\
& +\ 0 + E[V^*v(t)|v(t+\tau)|^2] + |V|^2r^*(\tau) + (V^*)^2E[v(t)v(t+\tau)]
\end{align*}
$$

Then, comparing the given expression and the expression I have, the following must true:

$$
\begin{align*}
& E[|v(t)|^2Vv^*(t+\tau)]+E[|v(t)|^2V^*v(t+\tau)] \\
& +\ E[Vv^*(t)|v(t+\tau)|^2] + V^2E[v^*(t)v^*(t+\tau)] \\
& +\ E[V^*v(t)|v(t+\tau)|^2] + (V^*)^2E[v(t)v(t+\tau)] = 0.
\end{align*}
$$

How do I show that it is true, given that $v(t)$ is a zero-mean Complex Gaussian random variable, with the given autocorrelation function? It may have to do with the third moment of a Gaussian random variable, with zero-mean, being zero, but I wanted to be completely sure of the result.

Thanks.

Comment: To add a detail, the thesis topic was channel propagation model in wireless communications.